# Apex error - Pricebook error

Tags: apex, pricebook, pricebookentry

//Please help me with error '**field integrity exception: PricebookEntryId (pricebook entry is in a different pricebook than the one assigned to the opportunity)**'

// **Below is the code.** It is giving error while inserting Opportunity Line Item.

// I really wanted achieve with **seeAlldata = false**

```
        Pricebook2 pb2 = new Pricebook2();
        pb2.name = 'Business A Price Book';
        pb2.IsActive = true;
        insert pb2;

        Product2 svc2 = new Product2();
        svc2.name = 'Analytics - Core';
        svc2.IsActive = true;
        svc2.CanUseRevenueSchedule = true;
        insert svc2;

        //*Standard pricebook entry
        PricebookEntry pbe2 = new PricebookEntry();
        pbe2.Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(); 
        pbe2.Product2Id = svc2.id;
        pbe2.UnitPrice = 1;
        pbe2.IsActive = true;
        insert pbe2;

        PricebookEntry pbe3 = new PricebookEntry();
        //*Standard forecasting pricebook entry
        pbe3.Pricebook2Id = pb2.id;
        pbe3.Product2Id = svc2.id;
        pbe3.IsActive = true;
        pbe3.UnitPrice = 1;
        insert pbe3;

       //Insert Opportunity record
        Opportunity opportunity2 = new Opportunity();
        opportunity2.RecordTypeId = rtMapByNameOpp.get('iVH Opportunity').getRecordTypeId();
        opportunity2.Name = 'TEST OPPORTUNITY-2';
        opportunity2.AccountId = account.Id;
        opportunity2.Type = 'New Business';
        opportunity2.StageName = '1 - Qualification';
        opportunity2.CloseDate = date.today();
        Opportunity2.Amount = 100000;
        Opportunity2.Total_Direct_Fees__c = 100000;
        opportunity2.Project_Start_Date__c = date.today().addMonths(1);
        Opportunity2.Project_Duration_in_Months__c = 2;
        opportunity2.Pricebook2Id = pb2.id;
        insert opportunity2;

        OpportunityLineItem  oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
        oli.PricebookEntryId = pbe3.Id;
        oli.OpportunityId = opportunity2.id;
        oli.Quantity = 1;
        oli.UnitPrice = opportunity2.Total_Direct_Fees__c;
        oli.Quantity__c = 1;
        oli.Unit_Price__c = opportunity2.Total_Direct_Fees__c;
        insert oli;
```

**Reply to Eric comment**
Please note opportunitylineitem is added with pricebookentry pbe3. Opportunity is added with pricebook pb2.   The pricebookentry pbe3 has association with pricebook pb2.

**I removed below code, still it is giving the same error**

**opportunity2.Pricebook2Id = pb2.id;**

**Here is the updated code**

```
        Pricebook2 pb2 = new Pricebook2();
        pb2.name = 'Business A Price Book';
        pb2.IsActive = true;
        insert pb2;

        Product2 svc2 = new Product2();
        svc2.name = 'Analytics - Core';
        svc2.IsActive = true;
        svc2.CanUseRevenueSchedule = true;
        insert svc2;

        //*Standard pricebook entry
        PricebookEntry pbe2 = new PricebookEntry();
        pbe2.Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(); 
        pbe2.Product2Id = svc2.id;
        pbe2.UnitPrice = 1;
        pbe2.IsActive = true;
        insert pbe2;

       PricebookEntry pbe3 = new PricebookEntry();
        //*Standard forecasting pricebook entry
        pbe3.Pricebook2Id = pb2.id;
        pbe3.Product2Id = svc2.id;
        pbe3.IsActive = true;
        pbe3.UnitPrice = 1;
        insert pbe3;

       //Insert Opportunity record
        Opportunity opportunity2 = new Opportunity();
        opportunity2.RecordTypeId = rtMapByNameOpp.get('iVH Opportunity').getRecordTypeId();
        opportunity2.Name = 'TEST OPPORTUNITY-2';
        opportunity2.AccountId = account.Id;
        opportunity2.Type = 'New Business';
        opportunity2.StageName = '1 - Qualification';
        opportunity2.CloseDate = date.today();
        Opportunity2.Amount = 100000;
        Opportunity2.Total_Direct_Fees__c = 100000;
        opportunity2.Project_Start_Date__c = date.today().addMonths(1);
        Opportunity2.Project_Duration_in_Months__c = 2;
       /* opportunity2.Pricebook2Id = pb2.id;*/
        insert opportunity2;

      OpportunityLineItem  oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
        oli.PricebookEntryId = pbe3.Id;
        oli.OpportunityId = opportunity2.id;
        oli.Quantity = 1;
        oli.UnitPrice = opportunity2.Total_Direct_Fees__c;
        oli.Quantity__c = 1;
        oli.Unit_Price__c = opportunity2.Total_Direct_Fees__c;
        insert oli;
```

Comment: I think the issue is you are assigning pb2.Id for opportunity and pb3.Id for associated OLI. You can try changing the Opportunity pricebook to pb3id,

Comment: @anurag, pls do not confused with variable pb and pbe.. Pls look at it again.

Comment: I see you commented the pb2 part from opportunity. Are you still getting the error?

Comment: @AnuragA, yes I am still getting an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error states pretty well what is going on:

1. you created an Opportunity with **PB2** assigned to it
2. You then attempted to insert an OLI with a pricebookentry of **PB3**

You cannot have line items from different price books that the parent opportunity.

To fix, depending on your requirements simply remove:

```
opportunity2.Pricebook2Id = pb2.id;
```

from your test code. The Pricebook will be assigned to the opportunity when the first OLI is inserted.

Also, note you can get the standard price book without using seealldata by executing `test.getStandardPriceBookId()`

**UPDATE**

I took your code removing fields that are not in my org the following compiles and passes a test (although it does not really test anything it just runs code)

```
@isTest
public class iWork {


    public static testmethod void doit(){
        Account a = New Account(Name = 'test');
        insert a;

        Pricebook2 pb2 = new Pricebook2();
        pb2.name = 'Business A Price Book';
        pb2.IsActive = true;
        insert pb2;

        Product2 svc2 = new Product2();
        svc2.name = 'Analytics - Core';
        svc2.IsActive = true;
        insert svc2;

        //*Standard pricebook entry
        PricebookEntry pbe2 = new PricebookEntry();
        pbe2.Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(); 
        pbe2.Product2Id = svc2.id;
        pbe2.UnitPrice = 1;
        pbe2.IsActive = true;
        insert pbe2;

       PricebookEntry pbe3 = new PricebookEntry();
        //*Standard forecasting pricebook entry
        pbe3.Pricebook2Id = pb2.id;
        pbe3.Product2Id = svc2.id;
        pbe3.IsActive = true;
        pbe3.UnitPrice = 1;
        insert pbe3;

       //Insert Opportunity record
        Opportunity opportunity2 = new Opportunity();
        opportunity2.Name = 'TEST OPPORTUNITY-2';
        opportunity2.AccountId = a.id;
        opportunity2.Type = 'New Business';
        opportunity2.StageName = '1 - Qualification';
        opportunity2.CloseDate = date.today();
        Opportunity2.Amount = 100000;
        insert opportunity2;

      OpportunityLineItem  oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
        oli.PricebookEntryId = pbe3.Id;
        oli.OpportunityId = opportunity2.id;
        oli.Quantity = 1;
        oli.UnitPrice = 123.00;
        insert oli;


    }

}
```

Comment: pls look at my comment again.

Comment: Please post your updated code.

Comment: pls look at updated code

Comment: @Razu - See updated answer. It works just fine.

Comment: All I did was remove the line I told you to remove....Glad you got it worked out

Comment: Actually issue was, I was by default assigning a Custom Pricebook to new opportunity when it gets created.  I didn't realize it was causing the issue.. Between insert opportunity and insert Opportunitylineitem added below code..    
Opportunity2.Pricebook2Id = null;
update Opportunity2;
your code execution code run confirmation made me think in different angle.. 
I was struggling last 2 days.. it finally worked.
Thank you again

Comment: Ahh, got it. At least the verification that the code was working got you looking elsewhere and helped to identify the issue.